# Selecting from a function that return object type alongside with the another table that gives the parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am having trouble selecting from a function that takes one parameter to calculate some amounts and then returns one object type that contains the data

Here's what i have done.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE AMOUNTS
AS
    OBJECT
    (
        AMOUNT1 NUMBER, --1
        AMOUNT2 NUMBER, --2
        AMOUNT3 NUMBER --3
    )
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CALCULATEAMOUNTS(
    ID NUMBER)
RETURN AMOUNTS
IS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        AMOUNT1 NUMBER;
        AMOUNT2 NUMBER;
        AMOUNT3 NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        --calculation of amount1, amount2 and amount3
        RETURN AMOUNTS(AMOUNT1, AMOUNT2, AMOUNT3) ;
    END;
END CALCULATEAMOUNTS;
```

What I want after this is selecting from the function result and from an other table `PRODUCT` that i will also need it's `ID` to calculate the amounts but I couldn't

here's my tries:
-try1

```
SELECT PR.ID, FUNC_DATA.AMOUNT1, FUNC_DATA.AMOUNT2, FUNC_DATA.AMOUNT3 FROM
    (
        SELECT CALCULATEAMOUNTS(PR.ID) FROM DUAL
    ) FUNC_DATA, PRODUCT PR;
```

result:

> ORA-00904: "PR"."ID": invalid identifier

-try2

```
 SELECT PR.ID, TREAT(
    (
        SELECT CALCULATEAMOUNTS(PR.ID) AS FUNC_DATA FROM DUAL
    ) AS AMOUNTS) FROM PRODUCT PR;
```

result:
[image]

I just want to return the field `ID`, `AMOUNT1`, `AMOUNT2` and `AMOUNT3` together without calling the function many time and each time to get one amount because it will cause a performance issue

Answer (score 0):

I've created a minimal product table:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
  id NUMBER
);
INSERT INTO product VALUES (1);
```

Now this query works:

```
SELECT pr.id, 
       CALCULATEAMOUNTS(pr.id).amount1 AS amount1,
       CALCULATEAMOUNTS(pr.id).amount2 AS amount2,
       CALCULATEAMOUNTS(pr.id).amount3 AS amount3
  FROM product pr;

ID  AMOUNT1 AMOUNT2 AMOUNT3
1   null    null    null
```

EDIT:

You could also nest the query:

```
SELECT q.id, q.f.amount1, q.f.amount2, q.f.amount3
  FROM (
        SELECT pr.id, calculateamounts(pr.id) as f
          FROM product pr
       ) q;
```

However, the function is still called three times. I checked with a modified function `CALCULATEAMOUNTS` that writes to a log table.

EDIT:

I found a way to avoid that the function is called three times: declare your function as being `DETERMINISTIC`. (Which it is, isn't it? It returns the same results for a given ID?)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CALCULATEAMOUNTS(ID NUMBER)
  RETURN AMOUNTS DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN ...
```

Comment: thanks,but calling the same function with the same parameter many time is not recommended since all the amounts were calculated in the first call

Comment: @NejiSoltani: Have modified my post. Should be fine now.

Comment: i dont know what DETERMINISTIC do but i will check that

Comment: "Tells the optimizer that the function returns the same value whenever it is invoked with the same parameter values". The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/function.htm#LNPLS01322) has further comments on what to do if your function depends on schema objects (as I believe your function does)

Comment: pretty interesting feature never heard of it, well then using that declaration I guess I am able to use the first solution you mentioned since it's more simple, i will check the performance and get back at you with an update

Comment: Sad news, DETERMINISTIC  and even RESULT_CACHE  doesn't work for a function that return an object type ..

Comment: @NejiSoltani: sorry, tested it on 19.3. Yes, can verify no chance on 11.2. Tried /*+ materialize*/ in the subquery, virtual column, but no hope. You could implement your own cache inside the function, but that's a hassle.